# Convert metres to the 1.25 to metres

Tags: dimensional-analysis, units, si-units

I have been given a constant, of value $\beta=3$ x $10^{-30} Jm^{1.25}$. I need to use it in an equation that gives a value in SI units (metres). How can I convert the value of the constant $\beta$ to one I can use in an equation in SI units? Would I need to take the 1.25 root of its value?

Comment: Note that $\beta$ *is* in SI units. It just happens that the quantity that $\beta$ describes is of dimension $\text{energy}\cdot\text{length}^{1.25}$

Comment: $Jm^{1.25}$ is a very unusual unit - can you give us the equation that $\beta$ is used in ? Are you sure the $1.25$ suffix is actually part of the unit, and not, for example, a footnote or endnote reference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constant can be written as: $\beta= \alpha J^{4/4} m^{5/4} $

If you want to use a different constant without fractional units, you can simply:

$$\beta' = \beta^4 = \alpha^4 J^4 m^5$$

Taking the "1.25th" root would still give a fractional value for joules. Note that the equation is already in SI units, it just looks a bit ugly to use noninteger units.